# How to extend a grammar in coq?

Tags: coq

```
Inductive ty0: Type :=
| Bool : ty0
| Int : ty0
| Dyn : ty0
| Arrow0: ty0 -> ty0 -> ty0.

Inductive ty1: Type := 
| ty : ty0 -> ty1
| Inters : ty1 -> ty1 -> ty1.

Inductive ty2: Type :=
| ty': ty0 -> ty2
| Arrow2 : ty1 -> ty2 -> ty2.

Inductive consist : ty2 -> ty2 -> Prop :=
 | cs_dyn1 : forall t2, consist Dyn t2
```

I have a grammar, which is ty0, and I want to create a grammar t1 which is t0 and other things. So far, I have no problem compiling this. But when I define "consist" and I say  `consist Dyn t2` it says that Dyn is actually t0 and it's expecting t2. How do I tell it that t2 is t0 plus other things?

Edited relation:

```
Coercion ty0_ty2 (t : ty0) : ty2 := (ty' t).
Coercion ty0_ty1 (t : ty0) : ty1 := (ty t).

Inductive consist0 : ty0 -> ty0 -> Prop := 
| cs_dyn1 : forall t2, consist0 Dyn t2
| cs_dyn2 : forall t1, consist0 t1  Dyn
| cs_same : forall t1, consist0 t1 t1
| cs_arrow0 : forall t1 t2 t1' t2', consist0 t1 t1' -> 
                                    consist0 t2 t2'->
 consist0 (Arrow0 t1 t2) (Arrow0 t1' t2').

Inductive consist1 : ty1 -> ty1 -> Prop :=
| cs_same1 : forall t1, consist1 t1 t1
| cs_consist0 : forall t1 t2, consist0 t1 t2 -> consist1 t1 t2
| c_inters : forall t1 t2 t1' t2', consist1 t1 t1' -> 
consist1 t2 t2'->
consist1 (Inters t1 t2) (Inters t1' t2').

Inductive consist : ty2 -> ty2 -> Prop :=
  | cs_consist1 : forall t1 t2, consist0 t1 t2 -> consist t1 t2
  | cs_arrow2 : forall t1 t2 t1' t2', consist1 t1 t1' -> 
                                      consist t2 t2'->
   consist (Arrow2 t1 t2) (Arrow2 t1' t2').
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a coercion from `ty0` to `ty2` and it will help quite a bit:

```
Inductive ty0: Type :=
| Bool : ty0
| Int : ty0
| Dyn : ty0
| Arrow0: ty0 -> ty0 -> ty0.

Inductive ty1: Type :=
| ty : ty0 -> ty1
| Inters : ty1 -> ty1 -> ty1.

Inductive ty2: Type :=
| ty': ty0 -> ty2
| Arrow2 : ty1 -> ty2 -> ty2.

Coercion ty0_ty2 (t : ty0) : ty2 := (ty' t).

Inductive consist : ty2 -> ty2 -> Prop :=
 | cs_dyn1 : forall t2, consist Dyn t2.
```

See https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html for more information.

Comment: I wonder if this is a good way to define the grammar in coq though? because if I want to say something about the Arrow2 type, it needs to take a  ty1 in the first argument. So it seems that something like this "forall t1 t2 t1' t2', consist t1 t1' -> 
                                      consist t2 t2'->
   consist (Arrow2 t1 t2) (Arrow2 t1' t2')." again won't work. Am I recommended to combine everything in one grammar? I could also maybe define the relation separately for each grammar.

Comment: I edited the relation. Does that look like the way to do it? It does compile..